# ArcMap convert mm to m

Tags: arcmap, cad

I have been given a DXF which is in mm instead of m. It also hasn't been spatially referenced.

I'm not too concerned with it being referenced in the right spot as I can easily translate it in another software package but is there anyway to convert it to m in ArcMap? I do have an advanced license.

Comment: What do you mean by converting millimetres to metres?  What is in millimetres?  If it's not spatially referenced and you can transform it into the right location, what part of it remains in mm?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a bit more info about you dataset and what exactly isn't working.  Include a screenshot or two if that helps explain the problem

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is very common situation, especially for some multi-disciplinary corporations. They even call GIS a new technology... Solution is simple.

Draw rectangle around you inflated drawing and extract vertices to point shapefile. Add geometry attributes to resulting 5 points. Apply this expression in field calculator on field Shape:

```
arcpy.Point( !POINT_X!/1000, !POINT_Y!/1000)
```

with Python as parser.

Save points, lines and polygons from CAD into new folder as shapefiles and start editing. Use spatial adjustment tools to match 3 corners of large rectangle and deflated points. Apply affine transformation, save edits.

Unfortunately it is trickier with annotations, because they are stored in database and working with feature classes might not work at all. Chances are you'll hit a wall with "out of bounds" message.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new projection, where the units are millimetres instead of meters.
Then use this when you georeference the DXF.